# WordPress /embed/ links

Tags: wordpress, seo

I noticed my website creates links like this: www.domain.com/post-name/embed/

I'm afraid this might effect SEO. Is it possible to disable this?

Comment: This is the `post-name` permalink structure. The best permalink structure for SEO.

Comment: @user2584538 I don't think you understand my question. Please read it again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is default WordPress behaviour. This plugin removes the /embed links: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-embeds/